# Android 8.1 Closes Activity when startActivityForResult() is called

Tags: android, crash, android-camera-intent, android-8.1-oreo

somebody come to my rescue.
I am building an android application that require taking a picture from the device camera and loading the thumbnail into an ImageView, note that I don't want to save this image, I only want to load it into an ImageView and get bitmap drawable from the ImageView later.

This is what I have Implemented:
To launch the camera:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if(cameraIntent.resolveActivity(activityWeakReference.get().getPackageManager()) != null){
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, UPLOAD_PICTURE_CAMERA);
}
```

Below is `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` invoked when `startActivityForResult()` is called:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == UPLOAD_PICTURE_CAMERA) {
try{
                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                    imageViewphoto.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e(TAG, Utility.stringify(e));
                }
}
```

The Problem:
The above code works well up to android 7.0, but on Oreo 8.1, the activity closes immediately the Camera is opened so `onActivityResult()` is not called.

This is all the log I could get:

```
I/PhoneWindow: isNeedChangeStatusBarColor taskInfo: [android.app.ActivityManager$RunningTaskInfo@c7a24ee] size: 1
    isAPPNeedChangeSBColor pkgName: com.a3lineng.softwaredev.freedom_app needKeep: false
    isNeedChangeStatusBarColor false
I/PhoneWindow: isNeedChangeNaviBarColor taskInfo: [android.app.ActivityManager$RunningTaskInfo@5566d8f] size: 1
I/PhoneWindow: isAPPNeedChange pkgName: com.a3lineng.softwaredev.freedom_app needKeep: false
    isNeedChangeNaviBarColor false
    generateLayout mNavigationBarColor: ff000000
I/PhoneWindow: generateLayout isLightNavi false, Visibility: 0
I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=505KB, data=398KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=495KB, data=332KB
D/BaseActivity: On Pause is called
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=505KB, data=341KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=505KB, data=341KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 2MB
D/BaseActivity: On Stop is called
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8857', transport: 'socket'
```

Who is facing the same issue on Oreo?, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Check required permission for MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Comment: @AnuragChutani, do you mean Camera permissions?

Comment: Any crash log ?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the log, that is all the log I could get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to figure this out in my case i discovered it is a user settings called Kill Background Activities that was enabled on the device. All i did was to uncheck it and the calling activity was available to receive the result from the Camera intent.

Thanks for helping.